# Set max bar height in horizontalBar chart

Tags: height

Is it possible?

I tried something like

```
        "elements": {
            "bar": {
                "maxHeight": 10,
                "height": 10
            }
        },
```

But it did not work...

When I have many values, it looks like this:

[image]

And when there are only a few values, it looks like this (and i would like it to be thin as in the previous image): [image]

Answer (score 0):

I reached to an answer myself.

First, I create the chart inside a div:

```
    <div id="chart-control">
        <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
    </div>
```

Then I change the div's height based on the quantity of lines[data.length] * (4/3)

```
    document.getElementById("chart-control").style.height = (data.length * (4/3)) + "em";
```